# Use DataSet values in jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, json

I have a `select element` that's going to be populated with it's option value dinamically. Those values will be fetched from a Sql sp(WebMethod in my C# code), called by jQuery.ajax once the page is ready, and the result of that SQL query is a `DataSet`.

I'd populate the `select` using something like `$('<option>').val('DataSetValue1').text('DataSetValue1Text').appendTo('#selectID');`

My question is, how would I transfer all the `DataSet` content to those jQuery variables. I'd serialize the `DataSet` into `JSON`, but what then? I'm not versed in server-client side interactions.

The DataSet is already done, but I'm not sure how to move forward.
Hope you can light the way for me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**WARNING BELOW IS PSEUDOCODE not real javascript code**

1. check jquery $.ajax method to see how will you interact with server/client
2. send JSON to the client (something like out.print/out.write)
3. do something like

> ```
> for (var _opt in JSON) {
>   //do the appending
>   $('<option>' + JSON[_opt] + '</option>').appendTo('#selectID');
> }
> ```

//I would never do appending in a loop. I would radther create options array and do single //
//append!!!

Answer (score 1):

Dataset is collection of Datatable
dataset(i) will give you the ith table

Table is nothing but a multi dimension matrix.
So this will be your javascript

1. Receive the dataset as object say `dsObj` .
2. Get the nth datatable by `dtObj = dsObj[n];` .
3. Now u treat this as a mulyi dimensional object `dtObj[i][j]` .

hope this works